# ImageMesh for continuous 3D images

Tags: image-processing, mesh

I have a 3D image containing distance fields, and would like to produce a mesh region from a contour at a fixed level.

I found two options for this

1. `ImageMesh[]`, works on binary 3D images, allows control of algorithms, marching cubes, etc.
2. `ListContourPlot3D[]`, extract mesh manually, no control of algorithm, cannot get a 3D region as output

I feel I must be missing a way to operate `ImageMesh` (or `ArrayMesh`) without having to turn my data into binary form, as `imageData` contains continuous values.  I do want additional control over algorithm, which is missing from the `ListContourPlot3D[]` way.

Can someone suggest a better way of doing this ?

```
distanceFunction = SignedRegionDistance[Ball[]];
imageData = Table[distanceFunction[{x, y, z}], {x, -1, 1, 0.2}, {y, -1, 1, 0.2}, {z, -1, 1, 0.2}];
fixedLevel = 0;
imageBinarized = Binarize[Image3D[-imageData], fixedLevel]

ImageMesh[imageBinarized , Method -> #] & /@ {"Exact", "MarchingCubes", "DualMarchingCubes"}
```

[image: ImageMesh output]

Note that `ListContourPlot3D` uses original continuous data, not binary image

```
g = ListContourPlot3D[imageData, Contours -> {0}]
g[[1]][[1]]
```

[image: ListContour output]
[image: ListContour data]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
DiscretizeGraphics[g]
```

[image]

Or refine the increment in the `Table` command:

```
distanceFunction = SignedRegionDistance[Ball[]];
step = 0.02;
imageData = 
  Table[distanceFunction[{x, y, z}], {x, -1, 1, step}, {y, -1, 1, 
    step}, {z, -1, 1, step}];
fixedLevel = 0;
imageBinarized = Binarize[Image3D[-imageData], fixedLevel]

ImageMesh[imageBinarized, Method -> #] & /@ {"Exact", "MarchingCubes",
   "DualMarchingCubes"}
```

[image]

Comment: DiscretizeGraphics[g] works great, thank you!

Refining the increments is not really an option, though, I hope to apply this algorithm to data that is {millions,millions, 3 to 5} in size .  Having more voxels will cost me a lot.  I would like to use an advanced algorithm i can control (like in ImageMesh), but with continuous data, like in ListContour...